# SELECT ERROR SQLITE.ALL - Prepare Error 1

Tags: angular, typescript, sqlite, nativescript

I'm trying to run a query on a local SQL db file that I have preloaded data into however when it runs I'm getting the error "SELECT ERROR SQLITE.ALL - Prepare Error 1".

I have tried getting the database connection in a separate function instead of using arrow functions as well as re-installing the application on my iOS sim but this had no affect.

I have a database.service.ts file which contains:

```
public getdbConnection() {
    if(!Sqlite.exists("drills.db"))
    {
        Sqlite.copyDatabase("drills.db")
    }
    return new Sqlite("drills.db")
    }

public getTopics() {
    this.getdbConnection().then(db => {
        db.all("SELECT * FROM drills").then(rows => {
            console.log("Selected")
            for(var row in rows) {
                console.log("RESULT", rows[row]);
            }
        }, error => {
            console.log("SELECT ERROR", error);
        });
    });
}
```

And in my menu.componet.ts I call it using:

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.database.getTopics();
}
```

Am I going wrong with how I connect to the local DB? It's stored under the src folder eg src/drills.db?

Comment: Have you confirmed that a) drills.db contains a table named "drills" and b) `Sqlite.exists("drills.db")` succeeds after the `copyDatabase`?

Comment: @IanMacDonald I checked the db file using DB Browser for SQLite and it contains the drills table, I just ran a console log after the copy and it seems to run, I've read the documentation but is there something I can run to check the success of the copy properly?

Comment: `copyDatabase(...)` method returns true if it was success, make sure it's actually copied. If you had not adjusted your webpack settings already to include DB in bundle, you should do that.

Comment: @Manoj I've added  `{ from: { glob: "**/*.sqlite" } }`, to the webpack.config as per the documentation. I tried your suggestion and returned the output of the copyDatabase to a var and it was undefined which I guess means the copy is failing.

Comment: But you are using `.db` not `.sqlite`?

Comment: @Manoj Thank you that fixed it! I wasn't using .db in my webpack.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make sure the DB file is copied in your bundle. The example code assumes you use `.sqlite` extension but since you are using `.db` you must adjust the webpack config accordingly.

Use,

```
{ from: { glob: "**/*.db" } }
```